# How to get anonymous profile for not current user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, profile

Good morning,
please, how can I get anonymous profile for not current user?
Profile for register users I can get with:

```
profile = (ProfileCommon)ProfileBase.Create(user.UserName);
```

But, for anonymous users? (class in App_Code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reply, but I want some like this, this working fine:

```
user = Membership.GetUser(new Guid(item["UserID"].ToString()));
if (user == null)
{
        // anonymous profile
        profil = (ProfileCommon)ProfileBase.Create(item["UserID"].ToString());
}
else
{
        // hey! I know you!
        profil = (ProfileCommon)ProfileBase.Create(user.UserName);
}
```

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't personally like the inbuilt profile stuff myself but I believe once compiled you can use:

Profile.GetProfile();

This doesn't work within static methods or if using seperate class libraries for that I think you'd need:

HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetProfile();

I don't know if there are options for retrieving anonymous profiles though as you'd need some way of identify which profile you were trying to retrieve.

Comment: http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx contains some information relating to migrating anonymous users which may provide more help.